# Restoring position when returning to ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are some posts here related to this issue, but I am trying to figure out what is going on in my particular case. Basically I have an Activity that instantiates a ListFragment to display a list of items that the user can scroll. When a list item is selected, I launch a separate Activity that "takes over" the screen to display details of the selection.

The issue is that when the Back button is pressed in this 2nd activity, the ListFragment's list is again displayed, but it's always repositioned to the top of the list, and I can't figure out how to correctly get the previous state of the list so that I could reposition it with setSelection, etc.

I do have a saveInstanceState in the fragment and it is being called when the details activity is launched, just as I would expect. However, I can't see any obvious fragment method that will be called to receive this Bundle back when the details activity returns. onCreateView and onViewCreated are not called again, and I can't use onViewStateRestored since I'm targeting API 14 (if that's even applicable).

Any ideas? This has to be something pretty basic that I'm missing!

Comment: if `onCreateView` isn't called, then nothing should reset the list, unless you do that from some resume method

Comment: This app was initially written for 2.1 and I just discovered that the "startManagingCursor" call I'm using was deprecated in level 11 (and my current minSDK is 14!). So I'm looking at implementing a CursorLoader, etc., which is not going to be easy but might help solve this. (My code is really starting to look hacked over with all of the upgrades I've made over the years.)

Comment: `CursorLoader` cache a `Cursor` across activity recreation, so they certainly help with decoupling the database request from the ugliness of activity lifecycle. And if re-requestion the data from a database causes your list to refresh, then yes, that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to the deprecated startManagingCursor was the cause. I removed it and everything works fine. There was no need to get into a CursorLoader since I am using a simple CursorAdapter with a local SQLite database.